# How to connect Entity Framework to Python

Tags: c#, python-3.x, entity-framework

I'm working on one project and I need use database in C# code. But I need that database can connect to python code. I'm consider Entity Framework for this project, but I don't know can I connect EF to python code. Or I should to consider another DB? Can anybody help me with this question

Comment: EF is not a DB. It's an ORM. C# and Python are different languages that can interact with DBs and each have their own ORMs. I'm not aware of a way to use EF in Python and it sounds like you're trying to use wings on a car.